# Checksum value from Minio Python Client

Tags: python, amazon-s3, checksum, minio, minio-client

I am uploading different objects in a bucket using amazon cli. I can put these objects in the bucket using a cli command like below and also mention the checksum algorithm,

`aws s3api put-object --bucket some-bucket --key some-object.txt --checksum-algorithm CRC32`

when I run this I get a response in the CLI which looks something like this,

```
"ETag": "\"some-etag\"",
"ChecksumCRC32": "some-crc32-hash",
"VersionId": "some-version-id"
```

Now my problem is that I want to retrieve this ChecksumCRC32 value from minio using the minio python library, but so far I'm unable to do so using the `stat_object` method and/or `get_object` method. Is there a different method that I can use or maybe there's another way to retrieve it?

Not just CRC32, but also SHA1 and SHA256.